# Mootools sortables serialize modifier not working

Tags: serialization, mootools, sortables

I'm using Mootools Sortables to sort a list, and i'm serializing the data and using a modifier so that the data is a bit more useful. This is my code

```
var order = mySortableTable.serialize(0, function(element, index){
          return 'item=' + index;
    }).join('&');
```

This should return "item=0&item=2&item=1" depending on the order of the list (obviously the label "item" is not very useful but I will replace it when I get the function working).

This isn't working as wanted, all that is returned is "0&2&1" with no item label. This code is taken straight from the Mootools documentation so it should work but it doesn't. Anyone know why this isn't working as it should?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've serialized a Mootools Sortables before, and I see no mistake in your code.

Could you give us more context? For example, the way you create your Sortables object...

Also important is how you identify the elements inside the Sortables.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the new information you gave us, I built a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wv6Cm/8/) with a simplified version of your Javascript, and everything works as you need. You can use it as a basis to update your code and find out why it is not working. I tested it in Firefox 3.6.15 and Chrome 10.648 in Linux.

Comment: @Nicolás Not sure if it makes a difference then, but i'm actually sorting a table rather than a list so <tbody id="myList"><tr id="row_1"><td>...</td></tr></tbody> - I have multiple albums which each have a separate playlist, each of those playlists is sortable. Please check out the Javascript http://kodo.ameoto.com/0264722453 - Thanks

Comment: @Wasim With that table, are you creating your Sortables object with something like: `var mySortableTable = new Sortables("myList");` ?

Comment: Actually no, I just used the label myList as an example to make it easier, it's actually more like `<tbody id="album_1"><tr id="row1"><td></td></tr></tbody> <tbody id="album_2"><tr id="row1"><td></td></tr></tbody>` - so there are multiple tbody's within one table as there are multiple albums. When sortables starts, it passes the album ID to the sortables function, so the sortables starts like this **function startOrdering(album_id)** ....

Comment: It is important to bear in mind that Sortables is asociated with an object (represented by the first parameter of the constructor) whose childs will be sorted. That's why when you use a list (`ul` for example) this object works with the `li` elements inside that list. If you are creating a Sortables object associated with a `tbody` the sorting will be made over the `tr` elements inside that very `tbody`. To understand your problem it's important to be sure that you are working this way...

Comment: I am definitely working this way, the sorting works absolutely fine, it sends the correct ordering to my AJAX url just fine. The problem is only with the modifier so that I can send `"label" + order` to my AJAX url for a more efficient PHP function to save the order. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks very much for showing me that on JSFiddle, figured out that i'm using an older version of Mootools that doesn't actually support the modifier function. When I upgrade my Mootools suddenly everything stops working, it doesn't allow $('var') style variables anymore...not sure why. Anyway I have found a workaround using the old version. Thanks very much for your help.